# Why a 45° polarizer brings back the interference pattern in the quantum eraser experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, quantum-eraser

I'm not a physicist, I'm just a physic-enthusiast.I have a practical sense of experiments and results but i cannot deal with the actual calculation involved.
I was reading about the quantum eraser experiment in this article:  laser.physics.sunysb.edu/~amarch/eraser/
and I cant understand why in this setup

[image]

I will not see the interference pattern. I've understand that the two QWPs are sort of "tagging" the photons and so the wich-path information is available but later on they put a 45° polarization filter before D2 like that

[image]

and this action brings back the interference pattern due to the fact that photons that hit D2 can be either clockwise or counterclockwise in the s beam.

The question is: in the first scenario (without the polarizer) both x and y polarized photons hits D2 (there is no filter so all the photons pass and x/y polarized ones are a subset of these) so why putting the polarizer (that let pass both x and y polarized photons) should make any difference?

Thank you and sorry if I didn't explain my question well.

Comment: +1 Welcome to Physics SE. It is always nice to see interested layman :) Thumbs up. Start thinking about the function of the two QWP. What is the phase difference? Before the quarter wave plate it is zero. They delay the light "in opposite direction". After the [QWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveplate) a phase difference of *half a wavelength* results. What does this mean for interference? Constructive or destructive interference?

Comment: I have somehow figured out why there is a half wavelength phase shift https://i.imgur.com/GbrkZhu.jpg  (in the squares there are the current polarization direction and i've computed the resulting wave by thinking if there are a constructive interference or not in the horizontal axe) is a naive approach but works for me :D. Anyway  why adding a 45° polarization filter on the p beam should bring back the interference pattern?

Comment: To extend your thoughts on your imgur diagram: introduce a quarter wave plate 1 and 2. QWP 1 delays by 1/4 and QWP 2 by 3/4 wavelengths. Resulting in a difference in wavefront by 1/2 wavelength. Hence destructive interference. In chat I'll provide further assistance.